# GET Method works on localhost but return 500 Internal Server Error on server (Django)

Tags: django, angular

I'm sending an API request from Angular to Django. The request is working on localhost but returns a 500 Internal Server Error on server. I tried running migrations, changing the API URL but nothing is working.

Here's my code:

```
@api_view(['GET','POST','DELETE'])
def get_favorite_annonces(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        favorite_annonces = []
        
        user = request.user
        all_favorites = AnnoncesFavorite.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)

        for favorite_id in all_favorites:
            annonce = Annonces.objects.filter(id=favorite_id.annonce_id)
            favorite_annonces.append(annonce[0])
        
        print(favorite_annonces)
        qs_json = serializers.serialize('json', favorite_annonces)
        return HttpResponse(qs_json, content_type='application/json')
```

my component:

```
this.ApiService.get_favorite_annonces().subscribe(
            data=>{
                this.favorites_list = data;
                console.log(this.favorites_list);
            },
```

api.service.ts

```
get_favorite_annonces():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.auth.getApiUrl() + 'favorites/annonces');
  }
```

Comment: Can you share your urls.py? What is returned by the server on DEBUG mode on? Django should return something to aid you.

Comment: here's my urls: url(r'^api/favorites/annonces/$',views.get_favorite_annonces). Nothing is returning even when debug is True, the HTML is working, but with a 500 internal error in the DevTools console

Comment: What does the console from Django application display when the error occurs?